# sum of square is equal to prime

Tags: number-theory

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p$ a prime number then I would like to find all $(a_1, ..., a_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n$ such that : 
$$\sum a_i^2 = p$$

Using a computer program It seems that the only solutions are $(1,...,1)$.

I don't see how to prove this result. An idea could be to look at the whole expression mod $4$, but it doesn't seem to help... :(

Comment: There are lots of examples...$1^2+2^2=5$, say.  Or $2^2+3^2=13$.  Did you have some specific thing in mind?

Comment: [Fermat's two square Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) is relevant.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A001156](https://oeis.org/A001156) for the number of partitions of  a given positive integer into squares.